# Erro na conversão de datas durante um insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso carregar uma tabela em um banco com dados de outra tabela e de outro banco. Acontece que no campo DateTime está dando um erro de conversão, pois os dados da outra tabela está em Varchar. Veja como eu fiz:

```
use [Rup]
insert into [dbo].[Ruptura]
(
    DataRuptura ===>>> AQUI DÁ O ERRO
    ,[IDJustificativa]
    ,[IDOrigem]
    ,[CodigoPDV]
    ,[Codigo_Apresentacao]
)

select

Convert(DateTime,stg.DATA,103)==>> Tentativa e não deu certo
,mot.MOTNM_CODIGO AS RUPTURA
,1 AS ORIGEM
,pdv.PDVCH_CODIGO AS CODIGO_PDV
,apr.APRCH_COD_ACHE AS CODIGO_EAN
from [STG_Rup].[dbo].[RPT_STG_CARGA] stg
join [STG_Rup].[dbo].[RPT_CAT_MOTIVO_RUPTURA] mot on stg.JUSTIFICATIVA = mot.MOTCH_MOTIVO_RUPTURA
join [STG_Rup].[dbo].[MDTR_CAT_PDV] pdv on stg.CNPJ = pdv.PDVCH_CNPJ
join [STG_Rup].[dbo].[VDA_CAT_APRESENTACAO] apr on stg.EAN = apr.APRCH_COD_EAN
```

O campo stg.Data é um varchar(100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido:

```
.....
select

Convert(DateTime,Substring(stg.DATA,0,10))==>> Aqui resolvi
,mot.MOTNM_CODIGO AS RUPTURA
,1 AS ORIGEM
,pdv.PDVCH_CODIGO AS CODIGO_PDV
,apr.APRCH_COD_ACHE AS CODIGO_EAN
from [STG_Ruptura].[dbo].[RPT_STG_CARGA_ABILITY] stg
left join [STG_Ruptura].[dbo].[RPT_CAT_MOTIVO_RUPTURA] mot on stg.JUSTIFICATIVA = mot.MOTCH_MOTIVO_RUPTURA
left join [STG_Ruptura].[dbo].[MDTR_CAT_PDV] pdv on stg.CNPJ = pdv.PDVCH_CNPJ
left join [STG_Ruptura].[dbo].[VDA_CAT_APRESENTACAO] apr on stg.EAN = apr.APRCH_COD_EAN
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifique o formato em que está essa string; alguns [veja este link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i)

Ontem mesmo "manobrei essa carreta"; eu passava um select com (@"{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}; depois mudei para (@"{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}.

Um formato "inequívoco" seria YYYYMMDD, mas não testei esse.

Boa sorte, caso ainda não tenha conseguido.